# Update Table with Increment dates

Tags: sql

So i have a query that updates an existing table with dates from 2 weeks. However I am running into a problem here. I get the dates updated into the table however, I want to be able to skip the weekend which comes before the ending date. here is my query and tables. As we can see below, i tried to add in a where clause but the result still gives me the weekends in the middle between the 2 weeks. How can i go about fixing this.
here is the sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35365/1
[image: after update]

[image]

Comment: do not mix business logic into data access logic.. make updates in your program code, not database. Databases are for storing/retrieving/querying data.

Comment: Next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
much faster.  We can't copy/paste from a picture :(

Comment: Also label your pictures. I guess last picture is **SOURCE** data and first picture is **RESULT** data? But what is you **DESIRE OUTPUT** ?

Comment: The reason for what I am doing here is too long for me to write out. All I am trying to do is just get the projectname to join into another table on Day. Which will lead to me having the ProjectNames as values for my SSRS report. My result data should not have 09/19 and 09/20, which is the saturday and sunday between the 09/14-09/26

Comment: i have added a sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying to update the Day in ProjectName table with only weekdays with a given range of dates, you should first identify the weekdays in your date range and then update accordingly.

First CTE (DateRange) generates all the dates between a given range.

Second CTE (WeekDays) removes weekends and assigns row numbers.

Third CTE (Projects) assigns row numbers to the records in ProjectName table in order to match those with WeekDays

and at last do the updates.

```
Declare @WeekEnding datetime
declare @Startdate datetime
set @WeekEnding = '2015-09-26'
set @Startdate = '2015-09-14'

;With DateRange AS (
    Select @StartDate NewDate, DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @StartDate) DayOfTheWeek
    Union All
    Select DATEADD(DAY, 1, NewDate), DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, 1, NewDate)) From DateRange Where NewDate < @WeekEnding
), WeekDays AS (
    Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NewDate) RowNumber, NewDate, DayOfTheWeek 
    From DateRange Where DayOfTheWeek NOT IN (1, 7)
), Projects AS (
    Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PkId) RowNumber, PkId From ProjectName
) Update ProjectName
Set Day = WeekDays.NewDate
From ProjectName
Join Projects ON Projects.PkId = ProjectName.PkId
Join WeekDays ON WeekDays.RowNumber = Projects.RowNumber
```

Note: If you want to filter the records you're updating on ProjectName you should apply the filter inside Projects.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35365/13

Comment: @Chandru how come? I just clicked the link and were able to run the script successfully.